# Can not install plugins in jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Gues,please help me.I can't not install anything in jenkins.
I don't have problems with iternet.[image]
I try istall plugins and appear next error:

`

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:559)  at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:600)    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)   at`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

i see that there was issue with artifactory 29h ago https://status.jenkins.io/issues/2023-08-02-artifactory-central-brownount/

there was bug in jenkins, see ticket/workaround [here](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-51849?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)
and jenkins dev said that they have already reverted this change [link](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/helpdesk/issues/2811#issuecomment-1061931925)

also check that your jenkins server has access to NET